# Can a column in dataframe contains different datatypes items?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

If i change one value of a column in csv file then whole column values are changed for example i have a column type int64 and i change one item from any integer to string then whole items types are changed to string by default when we read file like df = pandas.read_csv(filename). Actually i have to find item/items in a df column who have different datatypes from others like if i have column type int64 and there is one value of datatype object or float64 types in that column then i have to fetch that value as well as the row number of that value.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share an example of your input?

Comment: Actually i have two input files the first file is .txt file and contains column name and type  of column the other one is .csv and  have columns and  rows i am comparing columns from txt file to csv file after each name and type of column in csv file is matched successfully to txt file.I am fetching all the items in csv file by df.to_numpy() and comparing the items types to their respective column type. and suppose i have first column of type int64 in csv and if change any one item of that column to string then it impacts the whole items of that column and whole item types is changed to string

Comment: I think you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Column inside any data frame can only have one data type for all the cells of those columns. You can see it using:
`df.describe()` or `df.info()`

Comment: If i have a column type int64 and in that column there is one wrong entry of type string which makes whole column of type string then how to find that specific entry is there any way?